# Is it possible to paginate queries using OFFSET with multiplication?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Is it possible to multiply two numbers in the query for paginating MYSQL queries?

```
SELECT * FROM Posts
LIMIT $itemsPerPage
OFFSET ($pageNumber * $itemsPerPage)
```

When I try to multiply these two numbers dynamically in the SQL, I get an error about my syntax in the multiplication part. Is it not possible to multiply numbers in queries?

**My complete query**

```
SELECT com_id, time_stamp, comBy, post_id, comContent, IFNULL(likes, 0) - IFNULL(dislikes, 0) AS likeResult, profile_pic FROM Comments C
# Adding Likes
LEFT JOIN (SELECT likedCom_id, COUNT(*) AS likes FROM Comment_Likes 
GROUP BY likedCom_id) Cl ON C.com_id=Cl.likedCom_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT dislikedCom_id, IFNULL(COUNT(*),0) AS dislikes FROM Comment_Dislikes
GROUP BY dislikedCom_id) Cd ON C.com_id=Cd.dislikedCom_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, profile_pic FROM Users) U
ON U.user_id = C.comBy
WHERE post_id = '10'
ORDER BY time_stamp DESC
LIMIT 5
OFFSET (0 * 5)
```

For example the `OFFSET (0 * 1)` code above represents the pageNumber and itemsPerPage variables respectively.

**Error I get on HeidiSQL about my query:**

[image]

Comment: show your complete code  .. and you exact error message

Comment: @scaisEdge I have edited my code. Thanks!

Comment: Note that your query may not work as expected if timestamps are not unique.  Queries with different values for offset may give different query plans.   If timestamps are not unique, ordering will not be fully deterministic.  To make it deterministic, I guess you can change to "ORDER BY time_stamp DESC, com_id"

Comment: @oysteing Wow, good catch. Thank you! I also noticed that the pagination query messes up if there is a post insertion, while a user is scrolling down in an app. So, I also recorded the time that a user starts scrolls down and use it to filter out the insertions before it. I use "time_stamp <= $startedTime". But, your suggestion will definitely be an addition to my code! Thanks!

Comment: There are much more efficient ways to do pagination...  google "efficient pagination using mysql" ... i.e. preserve values from the last row on the current page, and then use those values in the query for the next page

Comment: Oh my god. These are amazing. I better review everything I did for finding more efficient ways, as my server resources are pretty limited! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  limit and can't use a calculation for pass the limit or a offset (you could use dynamic SQL).

In select syntax, the OFFSET is a subclause inside the LIMIT clause (see
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#id4651990):

`[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]`

```
my_value  = pageNumber * itemsPerPage; 

'SELECT * FROM Posts
LIMIT 100 OFFSET ' + my_value
```

and you should use order by

```
'SELECT * 
FROM Posts
ORDER BY your_col
LIMIT 100 OFFSET ' + my_value
```

Comment: Yes, my problem is that the multiplication part throws an error. Even when I try to multiply simple numbers. I have edited my post to include my full query.

Comment: Answer  updated .. the use of calculated  value is not allowed .. you should perform the calculation ouside the query and use the value inside  .. eventyally using dinamic sql..

Comment: I thought it would be more readable, making it easier to understand that they are variables. In Nodejs, they are actually in the form connection.escape(decoded.variable)

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing now. Thank you!

Comment: .anyway thye use of calculation for these param is not allowed .. as suggested in my answer  you need  a dinamic query for calculated  value   (or for param)

Answer (score 2):

`OFFSET` argument is a scalar value, provide a numeric literal or a single bind value.

If we need to do multiplication, we can do that in the client, and provide the result as single argument to `OFFSET`.

It appears the code is dynamically generating the SQL statement. We could do something like this:

```
$sql =  "SELECT ... OFFSET " . (int)($pageNumber * $itemsPerPage) ;
```

or

```
$offset = $pageNumber * $itemsPerPage ;
$sql =  "SELECT ... OFFSET " . (int)$offset ;
```